# ItemsControl ItemTemplate Binding picks wrong view model

Tags: c#, wpf, caliburn.micro

I rewrote the question:

Using WPF and caliburn micro, my binding to "Select" method picks the wrong viewmodel, when Select is called ('this' is wrong)

```
interface Base
{
    void Select();
    // and more, eg IsSelected, ButtonName
}

class ViewModel : Base
{
    List<Base> Items;
    void Select()
    {
        // now this=A which is wrong
    }
}

void Run()
{
    var A = new ViewModel();
    var B = new ViewModel();
    A.Items.Add(B);
}
```

The View contains this:

```
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <RadioButton Style="{StaticResource RadioButtonSelectorStyle}" GroupName="Main" Content="{Binding ButtonName}" IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}">
                            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                                    <cal:ActionMessage MethodName="Select" />
                                </i:EventTrigger>
                            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        </RadioButton>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            </ItemsControl>
```

Comment: What are the item types of the `Items` collection, is it a mixed collection containing multiple item types (or view model types)?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a mixed or composite collection, while defining the `DataTemplate` without a type hint by setting `DataType`, the XAML parser has to infer the actual data type. Now if the referenced (virtual) member is defined in a common base class or interface, the parser assumes a random matching implementation to resolve the reference.

If you are binding to properties, this behavior doesn't have side effects, except they are defined as `virtual`(what is rarely the case, because properties are not meant to implement a behavior, but to store a state). But since you are binding to a method, you experience unexpected behavior, when each implementation or specialization provides its own implementation of the referenced method.

The solution is to define the `DataType` of the `DataTemplate` explicitly, especially when dealing with composite collections.
In order to template the data dynamically, you have to define a `DataTemplate` for each item type. You can define them in a `ResourceDictionary` in the scope of the `ItemsControl` e.g. `ItemsControl.Resources`. Since the templates are implicit (without a key) they will be automatically applied to the current data type:

```
<ItemsControl>
  <ItemsControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type RadioButtonViewModel}>
      <RadioButton>
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
          <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
            <cal:ActionMessage MethodName="Select" />
          </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
      </RadioButton>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ScreenViewModel}>
      <RadioButton>
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
          <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
            <cal:ActionMessage MethodName="Select" />
          </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
      </RadioButton>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.Resources>
</ItemsControl>
```